# UnboundError: local variable 'item_url' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

In another function where URL is a separate variable everything works fine

```
def afd(url):
    url = '...'
...
links = [...]
async def ...(...):
    items = [...]
    result_id = ...
    for i in range(5):
        if result_id = items[i].id:
            item_url = links[i]
            break
    afd(item_url)
```

I tried nothing because I don't see any problems here and have no idea how to fix it. Some solutions from the internet didn't work

Comment: an equality comparison is done with 2 equal signs `if result_id == items[i].id:` the error indicates that item_url is not defined when `afd(item_url)` is called because the for loop finished without finding a matching id

Comment: Assign item_url = None before the loop.

Comment: This: `if result_id = items[i].id:` doesn't do what you think it does. If you are testing the value of `result_id` for equality with some other value, it needs to be coded `if result_id == items[i].id:`.

Comment: @Plagon I already did that correct, I just rewrote the code incorrectly

Comment: @AndreyIvanov TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @BoarGules I know it, I rewrote the code to SO incorrectly

Comment: @max That is why the instructions for beginners are so specific about copying code into your question *exactly as it is, without retyping,* and asking you to *test the code you are about to post* before posting it. Ask a silly question and you get a silly answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you are referencing a variable that is not assigned.
In this case `item_url` only get assigned if the condition `result_id = items[id].id` is met, which it's impossible as you are just evaluating an assignment (e.g `x = 10`) and not a statement (eg `x == 10`).

And even after fixing the statement, the variable `item_url` only is assigned for cases in which the item.id is valid, you should define a default value (e.g `item_url = []` assuming there is a different url for each item) in case the item.id is invalid or use the variable inside your if body.

Option 1

```
def afd(url):
    url = '...'
...
links = [...]
async def ...(...):
    items = [...]
    result_id = ...
    items_url = [] // default value
    for i in range(5):
        if result_id == items[i].id: // Correct comparison statement 
            items_url[i] = links[i] // Add valid item_url
            break
    for item_url in items_url:
        afd(item_url) // Invoke afd over every valid item_url
```

This is by no means the best implementation but more an educational attempt based on your snippet of code.

Comment: 1. I rewrote the code to StackOverflow incorrectly